# Combining Astropy FITS files?

Tags: python, append, concatenation, astropy, fits

So I have some Astropy fits tables that I save (they have all have the same format, column names, etc.). I want to take all these fits files and combine them to make one large fits file.

Currently, I am playing around with the astropy.io append and update functions to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

So I have it working now. This is what I did essentially:

```
# Read in the fits table you want to append 
table = Table.read(input_file, format='fits')

# Read in the large table you want to append to 
base_table = Table.read('base_file.fits', format='fits')

# Use Astropy's 'vstack' function and overwrite the file 
concat_table = vstack([base_table,append_table])
concat_table.write('base_file.fits', format='fits', overwrite=True)
```

In my case, all the columns are the same for every table. So I just looped through all the fits files and appended them one at a time. There are probably other ways to do this, but I found this was the easiest.